# Swift UI Remove Extra List Empty Cells without Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

**Swift UI - Xcode**

**Problem:** I have extra cells when my list is initialized. However, unlike other posts I do not have a navigation view. Is it mandatory to have a NavigationView in order to remove the extra cells from my list.

I have tried to implement a Navigation View but im not sure if its mandatory and how to properly implement.

```
.navigationBarTitle("List")
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

I would like to start a new Text or UIButton directly below the last "Current" cell without extra white spaces.

[image]

```
var body: some View {


    VStack(alignment: .leading) {


        Image("covidImage")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .cornerRadius(5)

        Text("COVID DATA")
            .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
            .bold()
            .lineLimit(3)
            .padding(.bottom, 3)
            .padding(.leading, 10)

        Text("Represented by Sate in the United States")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 0)

        Text("Current State: CA")
        .font(.subheadline)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)

      //List to Initialize TableView Data
        List(covid) { covidData in
            Image(systemName: "photo")
                .padding()
            HStack {
                Text(covidData.dataTitle).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

                Text(covidData.dataValue)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    //.color(.gray)


            }


        }//END List


    }//END Original VStack



}//END Some View
```

Comment: Use `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear e.g after END List add `.onAppear { UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not empty cells. The `List` just fills all available space and draws empty rows placeholders where there is no content. In your scenario is needed to limit height of `List` to its content.

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

For better visibility let's separate your list into own view named `CovidDataList`, then here is in your provided `body`:

```
  //List to Initialize TableView Data
    CovidDataList(covid: self.covid)

    }//END List
```

*Note1: The height of list updated in run-time so should be tested in running application (not in Preview)*

*Note2: I tested with replicated cover data model so some adapting might be needed to your code*

```
struct CovidDataList: View {
    @Environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight) var minRowHeight

    let covid: [CovidData]
    @State private var listHeight = CGFloat.infinity

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(covid, id: \.self) { covidData in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                        .padding()
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

                        Text("Value")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()).padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .anchorPreference(key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds) { [$0] }
        }
        .backgroundPreferenceValue(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { rects in
            GeometryReader { gp in
                self.updateListFrame(gp: gp, anchors: rects)
            }
        }.frame(maxHeight: listHeight)
    }

    private func updateListFrame(gp: GeometryProxy, anchors: [Anchor<CGRect>]) -> some View {
        let contentHeight = anchors.reduce(CGFloat.zero) { $0 + gp[$1].size.height }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {   // << required !!
            self.listHeight = max(contentHeight, self.minRowHeight * CGFloat(self.covid.count))
        }
        return Color.clear
    }
}
```

*Note: `BoundsPreferenceKey` is taken from [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62023131/12299030)*

Comment: Is this still the only way to  have a List or Form limit itself the size of content by default? Hoping there might be some style setting I'm missing built-in by now.