# SwiftUI - How to get size (height) of ScrollView content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to determine the height of the content inside my (vertical) `ScrollView`.

```
ScrollView {  
    //My Content
}
```

Is this possible? I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

Unfortunately, using simply the `GeometryReader` isn't working, since it returns a value of `10` no matter what content is inside the `ScrollView`

Thanks!

Comment: You can consider [this my solution for List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057285/12299030). It can be adapted for dynamic `ScrollView` as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution would be to have `GeometryReader` inside a `.background`/`.overlay` modifier. This makes it possible to read the height of the `ScrollView` content.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<1000) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
            }
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear.onAppear { print(proxy.size.height) }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

We get an output of `20500.0` which is correct.

Comment: Surprisingly, this also works with LazyVStack with reasonable performance!

Comment: For dynamic content in a scrollView, I change the `onAppear` to `onChange` and pass it the state that is dynamic, E.g. `Color.clear.onChange(of: chatData.messages) { print(proxy.size.height) }`

Comment: Doesn't work on actual device with LazyVStack

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution to this. You can use a `PreferenceKey` to propagate the size of the child view up to the parent. Check out this amazing article that goes over how to do this: https://zalogatomek.medium.com/swiftui-missing-intrinsic-content-size-how-to-get-it-6eca8178a71f

It's very similar to your solution with the clear color + `GeometryReader`, but obfuscates it into a nice view modifier, and sends the `@State` to the parent view.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hi, I'm a text")
                .readIntrinsicContentSize(to: $textSize)
                .background(Color.red)
        
            Text("Size of above is: \(textSize.width) x \(textSize.height)")
                .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func readIntrinsicContentSize(to size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(
                key: IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self,
                value: proxy.size
            )
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self) {
            size.wrappedValue = $0
        }
    }
}

struct IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) :

```
 ScrollView {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
         //print(geometry.size.height) 
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this one out, it always prints 10.0 out. This seems not to work.