# List View longer than its content (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My question is regarding the List in SwiftUI. I provide a picture and the code in order to present the problem easier.
[image: ScreenShot]

```
List(){
                    Section(header: Text("Notifications").textCase(nil).font(.title2)) {
                        Radio_Buttons_Group()
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Apperance").textCase(nil).font(.title2)) {
                        Radio_Buttons_Group()
                    }
      }
      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to get that blue line(it comes from Xcode preview, it represents the List View) to end after the last element.
Thank You

Comment: I think you need to show the code that make that blue line as well.

Comment: @swiftPunk The blue line is from Xcode previews, but I should have made that clear, thank you. :)

Comment: then I think it is just because of Canvas, did you actually run on simulator?

Comment: @swiftPunk yes I did, and it the space between List and "log out" is still there

Comment: @loremipsum It's my fault for not writing the question more clearly, but the blue outline is from the list. This is because I have the List code selected in the text editor next to the preview. :)

Comment: This is as-designed by default. List consumes all available space. This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057285/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi Yea that's what I thought too, the link you provided is very helpful thanks :)