# SwiftUI List Bare Minimum Height

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Below code results in the List occupying almost all of the height of the screen. How do I ensure that the List only occupies the bare minimum required height which can be dynamic depending upon the number of rows. Simulator screen shot attached for your reference. Thanks!

```
// om namah shivaya

import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            Text("Header")
            List() {
                TextField("enter your name", text: $name)
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            Text("Footer")
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Test")
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `.layoutPriority(0)` on your list.

Comment: Tried but does not work

Comment: Mention everything that you've tried. Have you tried using `.frame` with min/max/ideal values?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057285/12299030?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I don't want to set the height manually but get the List to compute the bare minimum height automatically.

Comment: `.frame` can be used with `minHeight:` and `maxHeight:`. It affects the way the layout priorities are calculated.