# List frame-height is not changing when the list items are increased in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm learning the SwiftUI language and I'm writing my first app for personal use.
So what I'm trying to achieve is when I write a name to add to the list, the name gets added to that list. However, the frame for this list is standard one single bar that even hides a piece of the first list item. I can scroll trough the list but that isn't how I want it to work. Is there a way to create a frame that is standard the perfect size for 1 item, and for each list item that gets added to the list, the frame grows in height to make it perfect. If you know what I mean

My code:

```
struct PunishView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModal = StocksViewModel()
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
             Section(header: Text("Lapsus")) {
                   TextField("Naam...", text: $text)
                   .frame(minWidth: 0,
                          idealWidth: 100,
                          maxWidth: .infinity,
                          minHeight: 0,
                          idealHeight: 30,
                          maxHeight: .infinity,       
                          alignment: .center)
  
                   Button(action: {
                    self.tryToAddToList()
                    },
                   label: {
                    Text("Voeg toe")
                        .bold()
                        .frame(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 60,
                            alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.purple)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                   })
                   .frame(minWidth: 0,
                          idealWidth: 100,
                          maxWidth: .infinity,
                          minHeight: 0,
                          idealHeight: 30,
                          maxHeight: .infinity,       
                          alignment: .center)}
                
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModal.stocks) {stock in
                            AdPistumLijst(title: stock.title)
                            }     
                        }
                    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                    
        }
    }
        .navigationTitle("Straffenlijst")
  }
}
            func tryToAddToList (){
               guard !text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
               return
               }
            let  newStock = Stock(title: text)
            viewModal.stocks.append(newStock)
            text = ""
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre] which reproduces the problem? It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you mean, so running the code and seeing the result would really help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/3JlMKZu

As you can see, there is now 1 name in the list and the frame is not scaled properly to give a correct display. 
Now I'm asking if there's a way to make the height of that frame scale accordingly to the amount of names in that list

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057285/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `List` in a `List`, which isn't a good idea. Unless you are manually setting the height of that inner-`List`, it won't know how much space to use.

You can fix this by changing:

```
List {
    ForEach(viewModal.stocks) { stock in
        AdPistumLijst(title: stock.title)
    }
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

To this:

```
ForEach(viewModal.stocks) { stock in
    AdPistumLijst(title: stock.title)
}
```

Result (example data used):

| With inner `List` | Without inner `List` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: with] | [image: without] |