# Views with Bindings causes AnchorPreference to return nil in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm working with AnchorPreferences in SwiftUI. The following code sends a preference up correctly:

```
struct BoundsPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = Anchor<CGRect>?

    static var defaultValue: Value = nil

    static func reduce(
        value: inout Value,
        nextValue: () -> Value
    ) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    
    @State var text = "Hello World"
    
    var settings = ["Option 1","Option 2"]
    @State var mapChoioce = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .anchorPreference(key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self,value: .bounds) { $0 }
        }
   
        .overlayPreferenceValue(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in

            GeometryReader { geometry -> AnyView? in
                
                print("Preference")
                print(preferences)
                
                return preferences.map {
                    AnyView( Rectangle()
                        .stroke()
                        .frame(
                            width: geometry[$0].width,
                            height: geometry[$0].height
                        )
                        .offset(
                            x: geometry[$0].minX,
                            y: geometry[$0].minY
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I add a `Picker` into the mix, for some very strange reason the anchorPreference stops working and returns nil. I have also tested this with a `TextField` and the same issue occurs. It would seem, any value that consumes a binding that could trigger a state change, causes the preference to return nil. Why would this be the case? If I used any other view i.e. `Text`, things work as expected.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    
    @State var text = "Hello World"
    
    var settings = ["Option 1","Option 2"]
    @State var mapChoioce = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .anchorPreference(key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self,value: .bounds) { $0 }
            
            Picker("Options", selection: $mapChoioce) {
                ForEach(0 ..< settings.count) { index in
                    Text(self.settings[index])
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
   
        .overlayPreferenceValue(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in

            GeometryReader { geometry -> AnyView? in
                
                print("Preference")
                print(preferences)
                
                return preferences.map {
                    AnyView( Rectangle()
                        .stroke()
                        .frame(
                            width: geometry[$0].width,
                            height: geometry[$0].height
                        )
                        .offset(
                            x: geometry[$0].minX,
                            y: geometry[$0].minY
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62023131/12299030? Pay attention on `BoundsPreferenceKey` there.

Comment: @Asperi, cheers that worked. With this said, it does seem like a work around. Would you say SwiftUI shouldn't be returning nil?